# PagingSource does too many requests

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging

I have implemented search using PagingSource and PagingDataAdapter.
While scrolling, PagingSource does too many requests, unclearly why, because I have few more PagingSources in other fragments that work properly.

https://vimeo.com/735648983
[PagingSource](https://github.com/MrRobot1413/Movies/blob/feature/search/app/src/main/java/ua/mrrobot1413/movies/data/network/paging/SearchMoviesPagingSource.kt)

[Adapter](https://github.com/MrRobot1413/Movies/blob/feature/search/app/src/main/java/ua/mrrobot1413/movies/ui/search/SearchRecyclerViewAdapter.kt)

[Repo](https://github.com/MrRobot1413/Movies/blob/feature/search/app/src/main/java/ua/mrrobot1413/movies/data/network/repository/HomeRepositoryImpl.kt)

Comment: Is there a reason you put your `RecyclerView` [inside a `NestedScrollView`](https://github.com/MrRobot1413/Movies/blob/781fe4e384ed4b51fbd3168a2d83bf3b207ee7ed/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_search.xml#L24)? That's never going to work (it'll load everything in your entire source) as per many, many other questions.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to have some other elements except RecyclerView, that's why I put it inside NestedScrollView. But it seems to work if I remove NestedScrollView. Any other notes about my code?